# i have a Tenda w150d ADSL router/modem and i want to use it as wifi accesspoint to share wifi single in my home for mobile devices and laptops

Tags: networking, router, lan, modem, wan

i have an Ethernet connection which i want to use for wifi in my home. i have a Tenda w150d ADSL router/modem and i want to use it as wifi accesspoint to share wifi single in my home for mobile devices and laptops.

i have configured it as ethernet mode with dhcp disable, but things are not working as i was expecting.

i tried both 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.0.1 as lan ip but things are not working.

please help me what should i do. i dont know much about network devies.

Comment: What device is providing your Internet and what is it's IP address?

Comment: i purchased Ethernet connection from local provider. he said that to put Ethernet cable in router and enjoy Internet services for all devices. when i tried to configure it i discover that he is using 192.168.0.1 for dhcp.

Comment: Who is providing ethernet? ISP or neighbor?

Answer (score 0):

This router/modem combo is intended for DSL service.

If the service you are being provided is giving out a address in the 192.168.0.0 network range, you can try connecting to the isp Ethernet to a LAN port, and putting the router address at 192.168.0.254 and disabling DHCP on the tenda.

If that doesn't work for you, you will need a router that has Ethernet for it's WAN port.

Regards,